# Flex Width not behaving as assumed

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm just now trying to learn the flexbox layout as it seems like it could simplify many things.

I'm trying to get 2 columns side by side with 1 60% width and the other 30% width.

Even though I specify the width in the flex-basis property they stay the same size, evenly spaced on the page.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLrWZY

HTML:

```
  <article class="fullCol">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </article>

  <section class="flexWrap">
    <article class="halfCol">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </article>

    <article class="halfCol">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </article>

    <!-- Put top and bottom drop shadow on navbar -->
    </section>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
  article, section, nav, aside {
    display: block;
  }

  #wrapper {

  }

  .flexWrap {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row || wrap;
      flex-flow:         row || wrap;
      -webkit-justify-content: center; 
      justify-content:         center;
  }

  .fullCol {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px gray;
  }

  .halfCol {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #888, 0 -3px 5px #888;
    width: 45%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    padding: 10px;

  }

  .mainCol {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #888, 0 -3px 5px #888;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    padding: 10px;
      -webkit-flex-basis: auto | 60%; /* Safari */
    flex-basis:         auto | 60%;
  }

  .sideCol {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #888, 0 -3px 5px #888;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    padding: 10px;
      -webkit-flex-basis: auto | 30%; /* Safari */
      flex-basis:         auto | 30%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use  `-webkit-flex: initial; and flex: initial;` on the flex child you are trying to define a `width` on.

Comment: Just add flex:initial into the rule as it is?

Comment: so if your changinng the class lets say .halfCol you would add it in there

Comment: Ok, I just tried that and it had no effect. I added it into my codepen as well

Comment: Nvm, syntax error. Works good now with your suggestions! Thank you

Comment: However, it know gives the col elements height which I didnt put there. Which was solved by removing the "auto" property